# Check first on tuple to see if matches with parameter

Tags: haskell

i have this doubt, and can't find an answer to my problem.

the bit of haskell code that does not want to be compiled :

```
type Prim = (String,String)

primeiros :: [Prim] -> [String]
primeiros [] = []
primeiros (a:xs) = fst a: primeiros xs 

nosPrimeiros :: String -> [Prim] -> Bool
nosPrimeiros x [] = False
nosPrimeiros x ((a,b):xs) = if (x == primeiros (a,b) ) then True
                                                       else nosPrimeiros x xs
```

basically what the first function does is

```
primeiros [("one","guy"),("yes","man"),("works","not")]
> ["one","yes","works"]
```

And the second function, checks if string "one" is embed on the first position of each tuple, if it is at least inside one, gives true, if "one" is not in the first position of at least one , gives false.

nosPrimeiros "one" [("one","guy"),("yes","man"),("works","not")]

> True

What fails? This is basic Haskell stuff, not being able to do this drives me nuts...

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Should "if (x == primeiros (a,b) )" be "if (x == a)" ?

Comment: Thank you immibis, give an answer so i can select it as the correct one.

Comment: Don't understand the downvote, i tried my best to explain the problem.

Comment: Ignore the downvote. Sometimes it is something small but legitimate (ex: you forgot to include the compiler error message) and sometimes it seems pretty inexplicable or illegitimate (ex: the answer might be blindingly obvious to the downvoter).

Comment: It might be worth to note that your entire source could (and perhaps actually _should_) be condensed to `primeiros = map fst` and `nosPrimeiros x = any ((== x) . fst)`. The less code you have, the less chance of errors (as long as it's still readable).

Comment: Thank you to you all. I've read all the stuff StackOverFlow recommended before posting, but i'm still new here and learning the manners .

Answer (score 1):

`if (x == primeiros (a, b) )` should be `if (x == a)`.